# Lapply para retirar resultados de teste ADF no R

Tags: r

Essa é a minha lista:

```
mylist=dput(mylist)
list(list(c(30, 50, 35, 25, 45), c(40, 35, 35, 50, 45), c(40, 
20, 40, 50, 25), c(35, 45, 45, 45, 40), c(20, 30, 50, 45, 20), 
    c(40, 40, 50, 30, 40)), list(c(50, 50, 25, 40, 45, 40, 35, 
40, 45, 20), c(40, 35, 40, 40, 45, 30, 20, 50, 35, 25), c(20, 
30, 50, 35, 45, 40, 25, 50, 35, 50), c(20, 35, 30, 25, 40, 30, 
50, 20, 25, 35), c(40, 25, 25, 20, 50, 30, 50, 40, 35, 35), c(50, 
20, 45, 35, 50, 45, 30, 45, 35, 50)), list(c(45, 50, 25, 25, 
30, 25, 35, 35, 35, 30, 50, 50, 30, 30, 20), c(40, 20, 35, 35, 
50, 20, 25, 30, 35, 20, 40, 20, 45, 30, 20), c(50, 20, 25, 35, 
35, 30, 50, 25, 40, 35, 45, 45, 35, 45, 25), c(50, 50, 25, 35, 
25, 35, 20, 25, 45, 40, 35, 40, 50, 40, 30), c(50, 25, 20, 30, 
40, 45, 40, 50, 35, 40, 30, 45, 35, 50, 40), c(35, 50, 35, 45, 
25, 40, 50, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 35, 35, 40)), list(c(50, 50, 
50, 40, 20, 25, 50, 40, 50, 50, 45, 40, 30, 50, 35, 45, 50, 30, 
35, 45), c(45, 20, 25, 20, 25, 30, 20, 30, 45, 25, 50, 30, 30, 
25, 50, 45, 20, 45, 45, 50), c(20, 40, 50, 25, 40, 45, 25, 30, 
20, 20, 35, 45, 20, 40, 50, 45, 40, 40, 45, 35), c(40, 40, 20, 
25, 50, 50, 35, 45, 50, 45, 50, 35, 30, 40, 35, 45, 25, 45, 45, 
25), c(20, 25, 35, 45, 35, 40, 40, 35, 35, 40, 30, 30, 40, 50, 
25, 40, 30, 25, 20, 40)), list(c(35, 25, 45, 20, 25, 30, 30, 
35, 30, 40, 30, 20, 20, 30, 45, 40, 35, 35, 35, 35, 25, 45, 35, 
20, 50), c(50, 35, 30, 30, 35, 45, 45, 50, 25, 25, 40, 25, 50, 
45, 25, 30, 30, 25, 45, 45, 30, 20, 50, 30, 30), c(35, 40, 50, 
25, 40, 45, 30, 25, 50, 25, 35, 50, 50, 50, 25, 50, 20, 50, 40, 
25, 25, 35, 20, 20, 50), c(40, 35, 35, 40, 50, 35, 25, 40, 25, 
25, 30, 45, 50, 35, 20, 50, 20, 20, 45, 50, 40, 30, 35, 50, 45
), c(40, 25, 50, 50, 20, 50, 25, 50, 40, 30, 30, 50, 45, 45, 
40, 45, 20, 20, 45, 35, 45, 50, 40, 40, 35), c(40, 45, 35, 35, 
30, 45, 40, 40, 20, 50, 50, 45, 40, 40, 45, 45, 35, 40, 20, 30, 
35, 45, 30, 50, 25)))
```

essa lista tem 5 entradas. Em cada uma dessas 5 entradas eu tenho mais 6 entradas. No meu trabalho cada uma das 5 entradas representa amostras de 5,10, 15, 20 e 25 observações.

Em cada uma das posições `mylist[[1]][[1]],mylist[[1]][[2]],mylist[[3]][[1]],mylist[[1]][[4]],mylist[[1]][[5]],mylist[[1]][[6]]` (Até a `mylist[[5]][[6]]`) eu quero calcular um resultado estatistico que é o teste ADF e pegar o pvalue.

Eu consigo fazer isso +- para uma media simples:

```
resultlist <- lapply(mylist, 
            function(x) 
            lapply(x, function(y) rep(mean(y), length(y)))
            )
```

Eu digo +- pq se vcs repararem na resposta a media vem repetida, deveria vir somente um valor.

Como corrijo isso?

Da mesma forma, eu quero fazer o teste adf e retirar o pvalue, e levar somente um valor, e não esse valor repetido.

Abaixo o codigo incluindo o teste adf. Não esta saindo. Alguma ajuda?

```
 resultlist <- lapply(mylist, 
                function(x) 
                lapply(x, function(y) rep(adf.test(mylist)$p.value(y), length(y)))
                )
```

Bom, e o principal, eu preciso manter essa estrutura do Lapply. Meu codigo todo esta em Lapply.

Alguma ajuda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Primeira questão**: as médias vem repetidas porque você repete esse valor com a função `rep()`. Se tirar essa função irá retornar somente um valor por lista:

```
resultlist <- lapply(mylist,
              function(x)
              lapply(x, function(y) mean(y))
              )
```

**Segunda questão**: o resultado do `adf.test()` é uma lista de 3 tipos de testes (`type1`, `type2`, `type3`). E cada elemento da lista é uma `matrix`. Para obter então somente o p.value você precisa primeiro selecionar o `type` (que escolhi de forma arbritária) e depois a posição do p.value na matrix (`[1, 3]`):

```
resultlist <- lapply(mylist,
              function(x)
              lapply(x, function(y) aTSA::adf.test(y)$type1[1, 3])
              )
```

Comment: Muito obrigada. Então para acessar o residuos de uma regressão eu posso utilizar apenas o `sumary(x)$residuals` comando?